# Identify prime number

Tags: swift, if-statement, primes

For some reason, it always gave me the wrong result. It's always `isItPrime = true` no matter what number was assigned to the "number" variable.

This is my code:

```
let number = 6
var i = 1
var isItPrime: Bool?
while i < number {
    if number % i == 0 {
        isItPrime = false
    } else {
        isItPrime = true
    }
    i += 1
}
print(isItPrime)
```

Can somebody explain to me what's wrong with my code and why the `isItPrime` bool outputs always `true` ?

Comment: Why is `isItPrime` optional? There is no *maybe prime number* ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem 1

The last iteration of your while loop

```
while i < number {
    if number % i == 0 {
        isItPrime = false
    } else {
        isItPrime = true
    }
    i += 1
}
```

does overwrite the result.

So you always end up with the following result

```
if number % (number-1) == 0 {
    isItPrime = false
} else {
    isItPrime = true
}
```

### Problem 2

Finally every number can be divided by 1, so you should start `i` from `2`.
So

```
let number = 6
var i = 2
var isItPrime = true
while i < number {
    if number % i == 0 {
        isItPrime = false
        break
    }
}
print(isItPrime)
```

### Refactoring

You can write a similar logic using Functional Programming

```
let number = 5
let upperLimit = Int(Double(number).squareRoot())
let isPrime = !(2...upperLimit).contains { number % $0 == 0 }
```

Comment: I really miss the `every` counterpart to `contains` in Swift. `(2..<number).every { number % $0 != 0 }`

Comment: @Sulthan that would be very nice

Comment: I have it as an extension but It's not the same :)

Comment: It is sufficient to have `sqrt(number)` as the upper limit.

Comment: The last line should be `let isPrime = !(2...upperLimit).contains { n % $0 == 0 }`
Otherwise number = 4,9,25... are count as prime

Answer (score 4):

Because isItPrime is overwritten in subsequent iterations, the last number which is checked, which is `number - 1` will always set `isItPrime` to true, because `number` and `number - 1` are coprime.

Instead of saving the value to a boolean, just end the loop when you found out that the number is not a prime:

```
let number = 6
var isItPrime: Bool = true
for i in 2 ..< number {
    if number % i == 0 {
        isItPrime = false
        break // end the loop, as we know that the number is not a prime.
    }
}
print(isItPrime)
```

Comment: One should start `i` at 2, not 1. Any number modulus 1 will return 0.

Comment: Correct. Fixed it.

Comment: It is also sufficient to check until `sort(number)`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I believe you mean `sqrt`

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with problems like this, don't be afraid to take out a piece of paper and manually see what is going on in your loop.

Your loop will go from `i = 1` to `number = 5` (because of the `<` operator.

With that in mind, we perform each iteration manually.

for `i = 1`, `number = 6`

`6 mod 1 = 0`, `isItPrime = false`

---

for `i = 2`, `number = 6`

`6 mod 2 =  0`, `isItPrime = false`

---

for `i = 3`, `number = 6`

`6 mod 3 = 0`, `isItPrime = false`

---

for `i = 4`, `number = 6`

`6 mod 4 = 2`, `isItPrime = true`

---

Last iteration of the loop, for `i = 5`, `number = 6`

`6 mod 5 = 1`, `isItPrime = true`

---

There we can see that the problem is that the last iteration will always have a module of 1, therefore resulting in in your `else` clause getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is always returning true because your while loop isn't working the way you want. Currently, it loops until `i` is 1 less than `number`. During that final run through the loop, `number % i == 0` is false, so your code sets `isItPrime` to `true`.

To fix this problem, try this code:

```
let number = 6
var i = 2
var isItPrime: Bool?
while (i < number || isItPrime == false) {
    if number % i == 0 {
        isItPrime = false
    } else {
        isItPrime = true
    }
    i += 1
}
print(isItPrime)
```

You may have noticed I set i to 2, because any number modulo (%) 1 is 0

I think it's worth pointing out, however, that:

1. You should probably make this a method
2. If you initially set isItPrime to `true`, you can dispense with the `else` part of your `if-else` statement

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
// MARK: - Function

      func primeNo(_ num:Int,_ divisor :Int = 2){
            if divisor == num{
                print("Num is prime")
            }else{
                if num%divisor != 0{
                    primeNo(num, divisor + 1)
                }else{
                    print("num is not prime")
                }
            }
        }


// MARK: - Use
 primeNo(6)    

 out Put
 num is not prime
```